# Risk of data contamination due to in memory processing - JAVA

Tags: java, spring

I am developing java application based on spring framework.

It

1. Connects to a MySQL database
2. Gets data from MySQLTable1 in POJOs
3. Manipulates (update,delete) it in memory
4. Inserts into a Netezza database table

The above 4 processes are done for each client (A,B,C) every hour.

I am using a spring JDBC template to get the data like this:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM MySQLTable1 WHERE CLIENTID='A' AND COL4='CONDITION'
```

and read each record into a POJO before I write it to a Netezza table.

There are going to be multiple instance of this application running every hour through a scheduler.
So Client A and Client B can be running concurrently but the SELECT will be unique,
I mean data for:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM MySQLTable1 WHERE CLIENTID='A' AND COL4='CONDITION'
```

will be different from

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM MySQLTable1 WHERE CLIENTID='B' AND COL4='CONDITION'
```

But remember all of these are stored in memory as POJOs.

My questions are :

1. **Is there a risk of data contamination?**
2. **Is there a need to implement database transaction using spring data transaction manager?**
3. **Does my application really need to use something like Spring Batch to deal with this?**

I appreciate your thoughts and feedback.

I know this is a perfect scenario for using an ETL tool but that is out of scope.

Comment: If you're that worried about data contamination you need to run a separate JVM for each client.  There is no way, short of your own coding bug, for Java objects to "pollute" each other.  You do need to be wary of the DB, though -- I'm unfamiliar with Spring, but having multiple threads going against a single DB simultaneously creates significant opportunities for interference.

Comment: BTW: Be very wary of "singletons" and static data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there a risk of data contamination?**

It depend on what you are doing with your data but I don't see how you can have data contamination if every instance is independant, you just have to make sure that every instances that run concurrently are not working on the same data (Client ID).

**Is there a need to implement database transaction using spring data transaction manager?**

You will probably need a transaction for insertion into the `Netezza` table. You certainly want your data to have a consistent state in the result table. If an error occur in the middle of the process, you'll probably want to rollback everything that was inserted before it failed. Regarding the transaction manager, you don't especially need the `Spring` transaction manager, but since you are using `Spring` it might be a good option.

**Does my application really need to use something like Spring Batch to deal with this?**

Does it really need it, probably not, but `Spring Batch` was made for those kind of application, so it might help you to structure your application (Spring Batch provides reusable functions that are essential in processing large volumes of records, including logging/tracing, transaction management, job processing statistics, job restart, skip, and resource management). Everything can be made without the framework and it might be overkill to use it if you have a really small application. But at the end, if you need those features, you'll probably want to use it...

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch *is* ETL, so using it would be a good fit for this use case and also a good alternative to a commercial ETL tool.

**Is there a risk of data contamination?** Client A and B read separate data, so they can never interfere with each other by reading or writing the same data by accident. The risk would be if two clients with the same ID are created, but that is not the case.

**Is there a need to implement database transaction using spring data transaction manager?**
There is no mandatory need to do that, although programatic transaction management has many pitfalls and is best avoided. Spring Batch would manage transactions for you, as well as other aspects such as paging.

**Does my application really need to use something like Spring Batch to deal with this?** There is no mandatory need to do this, although it would help a lot, especially in the paging aspect. How will you handle queries that return thousands of rows? Without  a framework this needs to be handled manually.